# Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

trying to run my Spring Boot application I get the following error:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured. 
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

After a bit of research, I added the last line to my application.properties file to look like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgreslq://localhost:5432/evaccine
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=passwordishere
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql
```

which then gave me the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.igorshiota</groupId>
    <artifactId>springweb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>springweb</name>
    <description>Spring Web Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any suggestions on what to try next? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Your JDBC url is wrong. Should start with `jdbc:postgresql` yours is `jdbc:postgreslq` no driver will match that URL and remove the `spring.datasource-driver-class-name` property you don't need it.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the help! I actually didn't understand when you say it should start with jdbc:postgresql and mine is jdbc:postgreslq (they are the same?) I removed the spring.datasource-driver-class-name and the error was the same as the original one:
Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Comment: No they aren't yours contains a typo. `jdbc:postgre**sql**` isn't the same as `jdbc:postgre**slq**`.

Comment: @M.Deinum omg, and that was actually the issue after all... thanks for highlighting the blindspot there! I literally needed a drawing of it (like "you actually inverted the 'q' with the 'l') lol

Answer (score 1):

Try to add word "Driver" to the last line of your application.properties file .
The last line will look like

`spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver`

Comment: Even better, just remove the line.

Comment: @Meg, I added the Driver and it gave me the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgreslq://localhost:5432/evaccine
at M.Deinum removing the line gave me the original error:
Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class